# How to know total pages of pagination in codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am using codeigniter 4, I created pagination in view and its display the results fine. But I want to know total page for this results. The view code for pagination is -

```
<?php if ($pager) :?>
   <?php $pagi_path=getenv('pagi_path').'search'; ?>
   <?php $pager->setPath($pagi_path); ?>
   <?= $pager->links() ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: I have not looked into this closely yet, but I'd try `count($pager)`, which should return the total of records in the $pager instance

Comment: Hello @Vickel, I've tried with count() but its not array that countable. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: ```$pager``` is not countable, because it generates with your record count and offset.

Comment: @kishor10d is there any variable provided by codeigniter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$pager->getPageCount() - gives you total count of pages

Class is located in system/Pager/Pager.php , you can look it's methods for even more 'extras'